# SublimeRepl não roda o código

Tags: python, sublimerepl, sublime-text

Eu estou usando o Sublime pra escrever alguns códigos em Python e o Sublime REPL pra "rodar" os códigos. Enfim, instalei pelo package control, até aí nada de estranho, mas quando eu coloco pra rodar pelo REPL ele dá "file not found error". Como eu faço para ele rodar?

Comment: Esse problema é no SublimeREPL ou no seu código? i.e. se você tentar executar um "hello world" ou algo igualmente simples, ainda assim dá esse mesmo erro?

Comment: Dá sim, são códigos simples pq são exercícios de ILP.

Answer (score -1):

Eu creio que o problema é apontar onde o python está instalado.

Verifique se a pasta de instalação do python está indicada nas variáveis do sistema. Veja a imagem anexada - [clique aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxmyY.png). Faça alguma operação simples através do terminal para ter certeza que é possível usar o python pelo terminal.

Estando tudo certo através do terminal, abra o Sublime. Comigo eu faço assim:

1. Salvo o meu arquivo
2. Em *View* > *Layout*, eu escolho Columns: 2
3. Em *Tools* > *SublimeREPL*, eu escolho a linguagem do meu arquivo.

Dessa forma, o meu arquivo fica do lado esquerdo e o interpretador do lado direito.

4. Agora eu clico na aba do meu arquivo
5. Em *Tools* > *SublimeREPL* > *Transfer to REPL*, clico em *File*

Dessa forma, tudo o que está digitado no meu arquivo salvo é transferido para o interpretador.

6. Aperto <kbd>ENTER</kbd> e começo a comemorar!

Comment: André, mesmo que suas dicas resolvam o problema da pergunta, seria interessante adicionar à resposta o motivo que leva aos erros mencionados, e porque a sua solução funciona.